# AppsFlyer doesn't show statistics about custom event

Tags: unity-game-engine, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

This code is called when the button is pressed

```
try
{
    Dictionary<string, string> eventParameters0 = new();
    eventParameters0.Add("test_parametr", "123");
    AppsFlyer.sendEvent("test_event", eventParameters0);
    Debug.Log("Success test_event");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.Log(ex.Message);
    Debug.Log("Failed test_event");
}
```

I get "Success test_event" but in AppsFlyer in tab events i don't see this event, but with af_purchase everything works fine and i see it in events in AppsFlyer. I forgot about something or custom events works some other way?

Comment: After a few hours AppsFlyer updated and i saw test_event in tab events